# Минимальное натуральное четырехзначное число, состоящее из тех же цифр, что и заданное число JavaScript

Tags: javascript, split

Дано натуральное четырехзначное число. Найдите минимальное натуральное четырехзначное число, состоящее из тех же цифр, что и заданное. Заметим, что четырехзначные числа не могут начинаться с нуля.

Напишите функцию с именем changeDigitsOrder, которая принимает четырехзначное число num в качестве аргумента и возвращает минимальное четырехзначное число, состоящее из тех же цифр, что и заданное число.

функция changeDigitsOrder(1500) должна возвратить 1005.

```
function changeDigitsOrder(num){
let str = String(num);
let arr = str.split('').sort();
.....
return arr;
}
console.log(changeDigitsOrder(1500));
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поставить число > 0 на место нулевого индекса? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function changeDigitsOrder(num) {
  let str = String(num);
  let arr = str.split('').sort();
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] != '0') {
      let temp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = '0';
      arr[0] = temp;
      break;
    }
  }
  return arr.join('');
}
console.log(changeDigitsOrder(1500));
console.log(changeDigitsOrder(5213));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое